# How to transpose my upload function into Helper in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

sorry i am just a beginner in codeigniter, but i want to create a generic uploading function. i was thinking if i can put my existing code into a Helper so that i will just call it whenever that i will upload a file. here is my controller function.

```
    public function multiple_upload(){
        if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
               $filesCount = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
               for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
                  $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
                  $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
                  $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                  $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
                  $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
                  $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
                  $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|txt|jpg|png';
                  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                  $this->upload->initialize($config);
                  if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
                     $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                     $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                     $uploadData[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                     $uploadData[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                  }
              }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper in `application/helpers/upload_helper.php`

add:

```
/**
 * uploadMultiple
 *
 * @return array
 */
function uploadMultiple() {
    $uploadData = [];
    $ci = &get_instance(); // need this to resolve the app
    if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
            $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
            $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|txt|jpg|png';
            $ci->load->library('upload', $config);
            $ci->upload->initialize($config);
            if($ci->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
                $fileData = $ci->upload->data();
                $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                $uploadData[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $uploadData[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            } else {
                // do something with the errors...  
            }
        }
    }
    return $uploadData;
}
```

Notice `get_instance()`. In a helper, there is no such thing as `$this` or CI so we have to "import" the codeigniter instance.

Then load the helper via `$this->load->helper('upload')` and you can use `uploadMultiple()`.

Note: I would highly recommend figuring out what to do with errors.

Comment: it works!. thank you so much, i still have one question. how can i get the return $uploadData to my controller? or is it okay to put my Models on the upload_helper.php,
im trying to achieve now is the inserting of it through my database. i am already inserting it on my database, but i still don't know how will i implement it on using the helper that you provided.

Comment: nvm. i already solve it!, thanks alex! its really a big help! :)